How do I combine subarrays elements into one array from a filtered array?
I want to combine elements of sub arrays into a new array from a filtered array.
For example:
Data:
Joe blue coffee steak fish
Jerry yellow soda steak fish
Joe black water chicken lettuce
John green water steak fish

Filtered Data:
Joe blue coffee steak fish
Joe black water chicken lettuce

filtered array:
[[joe, blue, coffee, steak, fish],[joe, black, water, chicken, lettuce]]

new array:
[joe joe, blue black, coffee water, steak chicken, fish lettuce]

IDEALLY: I would want the combined elements stacked like using CHAR10
Goal: My user is filling out a form with child tables that accept multiple entries.
My app script is creating a gdoc template that will pull information from the user form based on a unique ID. The child tables are tricky because they have multiple entries, and I want all of those rows of data for each column to paste within a certain part of the template.
function createDoc() {
    
    // Create a copy of the gDoc template through location of the gDoc file folder and setting a destination folder 
    const docTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1vqBztNAJZMU5HQPBEN); 
    const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1Gk_5a2EFTA); 
    const newDoc = docTemplate.makeCopy('Test Copy',destinationFolder);
    
    // Retrieve the values of all contents within each data table of the spreadsheet source 
    const appsheetFormat = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1wBr4wBu9OZ73Z1FBf).getSheetByName('Appsheet format'); //ACTION: Need to set up multiple tables 
    const appsheetFormatTable = appsheetFormat.getDataRange().getValues();
    
    // Pull the unique ID of the user-submitted form from Appsheet   
    const uniqueId = e.response.user.responses[0].get("Unique ID") 
    const uniqueId = appsheetFormatTable.slice(-1)[0][0];
    const moderation = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1wBr4wBu9OZ73Z1FBf6j5pongzjHMVfjxMdrNwHyPpUk').getSheetByName('Moderation Services'); 
    const moderationTable = moderation.getDataRange().getValues(); 
    const moderationLastCol = moderation.getLastColumn() 
    const moderationRows = moderationTable.filter(row => row[0] === uniqueId) 
    const combinedModerationRows = moderationRows.map()
    
    console.log(moderationRows))

My filter is working to get the rows that equal the unique ID (xxxxxxxx), but I'm not able to map or flatmap this function at all. .flat() or .flatmap() does not even show up as a function when trying to use it.

Welcome to SO! Please share a formatted [text table] with your sample data.

Is there something I'm not seeing, or you're declaring const uniqueId twice?

To clarify: what error do you get when you run your code?

Use code fences to format your code. Test formatting before posting questions.

Iterate the first inner  array[0] using .map to get  each column element with it's index and then iterate the rest of the outer array using reduce to get the same indexed column element from each row and join with \n:


/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
const fArr = [["joe", "blue", "coffee", "steak", "fish"],["joe", "black", "water", "chicken", "lettuce"]];
const stacked = fArr[0].map((c,i) => fArr.slice(1).reduce((a,r) => `${a}\n${r[i]}`,c))
console.info(stacked)
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>



